Foreach can't be used for variables of type "PropertyInfo" because "PropertyInfo" has no defintion for "GetEnumerator"
I want to iterate throug a Dictionary<string, object> with a foreach loop. First I get all of the items with reflection. And when item.Name is not settings the program goes in the else path. Here item is of type Dictionary<string, object> during runtime. But I get an error because at compile time item is of type PropertyInfo. Is it possible to loop over the Dictionary?
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = MyResponse.MyDocument.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var item in propertyInfos)
{
    if (item.Name != "settings")
    {
         // do something
    }
    else
    {
         foreach (var setting in item) // Compiler Error CS1579
         {
              // do something else
          }
     }
}

Compiler Error CS1589 at Microsoft Learn
I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.

This question is similar to: Get property value from string using reflection. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Here item is of type Dictionary<string, object> during runtime.

No it isn't; it is of type PropertyInfo (or perhaps some more concrete subclass like RuntimePropertyInfo). If you want the value of the property against a specific object (assuming non-static), then you get to get the value, via item.GetValue(MyResponse.MyDocument). That gives you object, though; if you know that the value is Dictionary<string, object>, you can cast:
var untyped = item.GetValue(MyResponse.MyDocument);
var typed = (Dictionary<string, object>)untyped;

now you can use the typed features, such as foreach
